# E QUERY [thread1] SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal @(shell) in 'mongodb'?

Tags: mongodb

my first mongodb query is executing perfectly while the second one the _id field is creatting some bug ?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++){db.mediafiles.insert({x : i,from_email: '123@gmail.com'})}
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++){db.mediafiles.insert({x : i,from_email: '123@gmail.com',_id:59193333aed3eb391e396a5d})}
E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal @(shell):1:90
```

Comment: Did you try adding single quotes for _id value (i.e. 59193333aed3eb391e396a5d)?

Comment: ya yet same results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will just explain the difference between the first and second query.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

**ObjectId** - is the unique key of the collection. If it is not mentioned in the INSERT, mongodb automatically populates the data. So, the first query succeeds for the 25 iterations.

Whereas, in the second INSERT query, you are trying to populate the value. So, you need to provide unique key for `ObjectId`. Otherwise, you will get `E11000 duplicate key error collection` error.

The below code should resolve the problem. The below code created the ObjectId and set the value in the insert.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++) { 
    id = ObjectId();
    db.AbcSchema.insert({x : i, from_email: '123@gmail.com',_id: id})
};
```

Comment: Good. Would you like to accept the answer? You just need to click the right button. Thanks.